# Notation for point of intersection in euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, notation, euclidean-geometry

Since there are signs for things such as paralell, $\parallel$, and perpendicular, $\perp$, is there any sign for a point of intersection? Should one use $\cap$?
This would be useful in writing instructions for constructing some geometric shapes.

Comment: Why not, but maybe prefer the standard size version, $\cap$.

Comment: Yes, we can write $P \in l_1 \cap l_2$. See e.g. W.Richter, [A MINIMAL VERSION OF HILBERT’S AXIOMS FOR PLANE GEOMETRY](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a3e1/5c85358a54ec6e7fc114ec317aa64bec3891.pdf).

Comment: Right. I'm guessing $\cap$ is part of set theory tho, wich someone reading about euclidean geometry might not be too familliar with. Could one perhaps use +? Since it looks more like an intersection. Or could A+B mean "a segment with the length of the sum of A and B"? + could also be typed on a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there is no well-known notation that doesn't overlap with a different usage in a different area of mathematics, so best define the symbols you want to use before first usage.

When you treat a line as a set of points, then $g\cap h=\{P\}$ would be accepted set-theoretic notation for that as intersection of sets. People will likely understand $P=g\cap h$ without curly braces to mean the same, particularly since "$\cap$" is pronounced as "intersect" in set context which matches your geometric meaning, too. Strictly speaking it's a different use of that symbol, though.

In many areas a line is not just a set of points, but a geometric entity in its own regard. In the lectures I heard (and later taught) we used $\wedge$ to denote intersection, and pronounced the operation "meet". The counterpart to this was $\vee$ pronounced "join" to denote the operation of joining two points to obtain a line through them. All of this was in a context of projective geometry, where the roles of points and lines are fairly symmetric, so having similar symbols for these fundamental operations was very useful.

This use of $\wedge$ was I believe inspired by the set notation, but the symbol is also used in logic to denote "[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)". It would be a poor choice in situations where both logic and geometry are used. And it does require a definition at first use, to avoid confusing the audience.

The symbols and operator names for join and meet are also described in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) in the context of ordered sets and lattices. There is a relation to the geometric operations I described but it's not as obvious as an explicit definition in a given context would make it.

Yet another usage of $\wedge$ is in [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) but the conventional geometric interpretation of that is more like the "join" I defined above. I guess by the time people are familiar with exotic things like exterior algebra, they are also familiar with symbols changing their meaning depending on context.

Using $+$ for this operation, as you suggest in a comment, would feel weird to me. But that may be because I tend to perform many of my geometric operations at an algebraic level using coordinates, so I would be inclined to read that as vector addition. If you are speaking to an audience not familiar with coordinate-based geometry, using plus might be an option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! This makes me quite curious as to why, seemingly, no common notation for point of intersection had developed before the foundation of set theory in the 1800s. I've read some of Euclid's Elementa, and he often uses points of intersection in his proofs. Is the modern notation for geometry even newer than set theory? That would explain why $\cap$ would be reused in geometry, however this makes me wonder how mathematicians would communicate before then if they didn't speak the same language.